# How to run crystal report in Windows Azure website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, azure-web-app-service

I created a web application Asp.net MVC3 with crystal reports. But when i deployed to windows Azure website. it showing an error message

The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception" CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException:An error has occured 
while attempting to load the crystal report runtime.

As it is Azure websites, can't create web roles or anything. Please suggest an idea to view crystal report in windows azure web.

Comment: Try setting **Enable 32-Bit Application** to `False` in Application pool's advanced setting.

Comment: As i am new to to azure websites how to set in Application Pool?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> 1. Open 'Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
> 2. Expand the server and click on 'Application Pools' to display available applicaiton pools.
> 3. Right-click on your 'AppPool' and select 'Advanced Settings'.
> 4. Change the value of 'Enable 32-bit Applications' to False. Click OK.
> 5. In the Actions panel on the right side, click "Set applicaton pool defaults" and repeat step 4.
> 6. Restart IIS service by highlighting IIS server name in left panel and clicking Restart under Actions panel.